# Can you roll in Star Wars Battlefront PC?

Tags: pc, star-wars-battlefront

I have been playing SW Battlefront for quite some time and I have noticed that sometimes (while shooting at a CPU) they seem to roll away which results into me shooting out into nowhere. I was wondering if I could do the same; it would be really useful.
How do you roll(dodge) away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I believe the default key is alt.  More importantly, if you roll away from an explosion it seems to negate some of the damage; this makes thermal detonators easier to avoid.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't had time to try this but as soon as have time to play I will.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean star wars battlefront 1, you have to use a strafe key and push spacebar.

Comment: What If I'm playing on an xbox one? can you roll then?

Answer (score 0):

The default key for this is hold Alt then press A for roll left and hold Alt then press D for roll right.